# Is "?&" valid for query strings in a url

Tags: url, browser

Is it valid to leave out the first parameter in the query string for a url?

```
http://www.asdf.com/?&foo=bar&foo2=bar2
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this means an empty parameter, followed by "foo" and "foo2" parameters.

Chrome and Firefox seem to be interpreting the query parameters correctly even when the first one is left out, but I wanted to make sure this was actually valid?

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

```
3.  Syntax Components

   The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
   components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
   fragment.

      URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

...

3.4.  Query

   The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
   data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
   resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
   (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
   mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
   or by the end of the URI.
```

Thus, the URL `http://www.asdf.com/?&foo=bar&foo2=bar2` is broken up as:

```
[http] ":" [//www.asdf.com/] "?" [&foo=bar&foo2=bar2]
```

Depending on who parses the *query* string for you, they will be able to recognize that the first `&` is invalid. Here is a sample parser.

```
var query_string = "&foo=bar&foo2=bar2";
query_string.split("&").forEach(function(value) {    
     console.log(value.split("=")); 
 });
```

output:

```
[""]
["foo", "bar"]
["foo2", "bar2"]
```

Key value pairs, will require a key and a value. You can decide if they are valid by checking if the array is length === 2.

Comment: The wording of Section 3.4 is a little misleading. If you look at the formal syntax defined in Section 3, `URI = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]`, you can clearly see that the `"?"` is not part of the `query` component itself, it is a delimiter to separate the `hier-part` and `query` components.  So your `split()` example is broken in that the `"?"` should not be in the `query_string` variable to begin with.

Comment: true. and I remembered that after I answered. The problem is that strings are immutable in JavaScript and creating a new string from the "raw" original string would have been too much typing for me at this point in the day. It'd be nice to have mutable strings and be able to use String.shift()

Comment: So it's perfectly valid to leave the first parameter off (by doing ?&) ?