# How to disable "?i=1" parameter in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

My website is running on InfinityFree hosting and it ads `?i=1` suffixes (like `www.mysite.com/?i=1`, or `/?i=2`, or `/?i=3`) to every URL *to protect websites against malicious bots*, as they say.

But of course, I don't like these suffixes and want to disable them (simply redirecting `www.mysite.com/anypage/?i=1` to `www.mysite.com/anypage/`). Note that I don't want to disable all GET parameters, but only these `i=1`, `i=2` and `i=3`.

I think it could be done using `.htaccess`. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You should probably ask them how to turn it off if it's causing you a problem.  This is definitely not a question for Stack Overflow, which is a programming Q&A Site. You could ask at webmasters.stackexchange.com but they'll almost certainly want to know what you mean by 'adds a suffix'  does it return a http redirect to the new url? Does it modify all links in your HTML? etc.

Comment: @JeffUK, they say it's necessary for InfinityFree users, so I can't disable it in a "legal" way. I just want to know if there's a htaccess code to redirect all the URLs with "I" to the URLs without it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, I've solved the problem using a code from [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573035/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url) question.
I've just added this code in my .htaccess, and now it redirects all the URLs with "i" to the URLs without it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)i=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: worked very well.. but now browser is showing that **tracking attempt blocked**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the RewriteEngine on first.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)i=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't edit accepted answer.

Added regex "&?" to avoid [empty key/value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31307075/7598333):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)i=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```